# Sandboxed Javascript Execution in an Internet Explorer Extension (BHO)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sandbox, bho

Firefox has the Sandbox and evalInSandbox(). Chrome has sandboxed execution in their content scripts (they call it isolated execution). I'm looking for the same thing in an IE browser extension.

I can load a javascript file, then call evalScript(), but the code executes in the same environment as javascript that exists on the page. I need a way to run my library (which includes and is based on jQuery) in an sandboxed/isolated environment, but still allow it to modify the DOM as if it were running on the page.

Jint looks promising, but cannot currently evaluate jQuery. (They can parse it.)

How can I do this?

Comment: Chrome's Isolated World: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment

"Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page."

Comment: Firefox's evalInSandbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Components.utils.evalInSandbox

This method is used by GreaseMonkey to allow javascript execution outside the context of the page. Passing in the DOM as a variable allows the script to modify the DOM without allowing the page's javascript access to it's own methods and variables.

This does allow for the sandboxed code to plant script tags and load content in the main page, but preventing that is not my concern.

Comment: I'm not convinced that evalInSandbox really works like you think it does; see the code sample in the Security section. While I'm not an expert, my understanding is that evalInSandbox is primarily useful to allow JS that would otherwise execute in the full-trust Chrome zone to instead execute in the limited-trust zone of the active document.

Comment: I think everyone is just afraid to tell you that they don't know the answer to your question. They're not answers. I don't have one either, but I'm just sayin'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are in a pickle with this one.

- Some Microsoft people say that IE doesn't offer this functionality
- Some who say they have been able to pull this off hold it close and protect it as their secret sauce
- "Professional" IE extension shops, when contacted about building what you are talking about turn down the job

I really wish I had better news but it looks like it might take a small miracle to accomplish what you are looking for... or maybe a lot of money. : )

Your best bet is probably going to be finding one of the few who claim they have been able to do it and pay them a lot to share the secret or reconsider why you really want what you want and see if you can't accomplish it another way.

Answer (score 2):

You might find it worthwhile looking at the Microsoft Web Sandbox at the Live Labs:
http://websandbox.livelabs.com/

Although it's more fully fledged and related to mashups and the like it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: The Microsoft Web Sandbox protects a page from scripts loaded into it. I need to protect the loaded script from the page. It's a good project, but doesn't help me here.

Answer (score 2):

Thing you are looking for is ActiveScript engine (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting)

I can`t find any usefull links now, MSDN contains only interfaces definition (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccd0zt2w(v=vs.85).aspx)
Try to Google "Active Scripting" (not "Action scripting"!)

You need to implement interface IActiveScriptHost in your extension, create an object of «JScript», call SetSite and pass your host object, then you can load your js code into this engine and run it.

This technique is a quite difficult due to lack of documentation about it.
If you are still interested in this, I can send you some examples in C++/ATL.

Comment: If you could put an example code here and maybe in GitHub that would be really helpful. Especially since like you said - documentation is sparse.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate on your goals a bit?

I don't think you've clearly defined what you're trying to accomplish. If your code has the ability to modify the page's DOM, then it effectively *is* executing in the context of the page. It can create new script blocks to perform any unsafe or unreliable action that it could accomplish were it operating in the same execution environment.

IE doesn't offer a feature to do what you're asking, and I'm not convinced that the Firefox and Chrome features work the way that you expect that they do.

Comment: My goals include running javascript on the page, without the page's javascript being able to access my javascript's methods and variables. I also want a fresh copy of javascript. If the page has redefined a method in javascript, I don't want to be subject to their redefinition.
I'm not worried about my script's ability to plant script tags in the DOM to jump out of the sandbox. What I have described is available in Firefox and Chrome. I'll post links to the relevant documentation.